# How to make Trail go backwards?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have set up a game in which you are a line drawn by a moving TrailRenderer. How do I make it go backwards (think trailRenderer going back in time) without making it overlap with the pre-existing trail? Thanks.

Edit: It would look like [this snake going backwards](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VP6hGXPlfEw) if the head was where the TrailRenderer was located.

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail about the effect that you're trying to achieve? If you're looking for something like [marching ants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_ants), that's probably something you could do with one line/trail that uses transparency and a scrolling texture.

Comment: To summarise you will put trail render onto the top of snake head and when the snake moves forward the trail renderer leaves its trail and that time when the snake move backwards you want the previous trail to be disappeared as the snake moves back . Am I correct?

Comment: @PraveenPanishetti That's absolutely correct

Comment: Have you tried anything and struggling with it ?

Comment: Well, yes. I was about to make a script where it records the position where you turned to then translate back to that if you die, until leaving the camera view. I have also heard that this could be possible with LineRenderer, but the game is practically built upon TrailRenderer.